# How can I check the OS version of an Android device?

Tags: android-versions

I just bought an Xperia x10. How can I check what version of Android it has?

Comment: This is broadly applicable so I edited it, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at `Settings -> About phone -> Firmware version` (or similar).

Comment: Other users: Feel free to edit in any other places it shows up, since I know there are a few devices that have changed it for no good reason :P

Answer (score 1):

On the HTC Desire (and probably most HTC devices) `Settings -> About phone -> Software information`

Comment: must be an HTC thing, my Evo does that too

Answer (score -1):

Look at settings about device or phone or tablet, press android version again and again.  If it's Jelly Bean a jelly bean face will be shown, if it's KitKat a K will be shown.