# How do I determine which version of Android operating system my HTC incredible phone is running?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check the OS version of an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/how-can-i-check-the-os-version-of-an-android-device)

How do I determine which version of Android operating system my HTC incredible phone is running? This is a Verizon phone.