# just got a galaxy few hours ago and have two questions

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check the OS version of an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/how-can-i-check-the-os-version-of-an-android-device)
>   [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

1. How can one know which android version is installed on the phone?
2. How can i remove the 20+ apps which installed on the phone? The remove button is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Menu -> Settings -> About Phone and in the list you should see Android Version
2. You would have to root in on order to do that since they're built into the ROM.